# c/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin/bundle: jruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I follow some of the online tutorial and install jruby. But turns out, i don't need that so i uninstall it . But when i **bundle install**
`sh.exe": /c/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin/bundle: jruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` this error is shown. I must admit that i am new to Ruby on rails. i spend several hours to find a solution on google but still stuck in it. **I hope you guy can help me !**

```
sh.exe": /c/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin/bundle: jruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like a messed-up `#!` line to me. What does the first line of _bundle_ look like?

Comment: Fixed!!!!
i just messed up.
just need to delete the extension file.
Thz